# How to I equate double values to string label? (This is for a caculator app I'm building in xcode Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, double, calculator

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Arithmetic Calculator
//
//  Created by Mapondera, Tanaka on 10/7/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Mapondera, Tanaka. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var calculatorDisplay: UILabel!

    var isEnteredNumber = false
    var firstNumber:Double = 0.0
    var secondNumber:Double = 0.0
    var operation = ""
    var result:Double = 0.0

    @IBAction func numberPunched(sender: AnyObject) {
        // number
        var number = sender.currentTitle

        if isEnteredNumber {
            calculatorDisplay.text = calculatorDisplay.text! + number!!
        } else {
            calculatorDisplay.text = number
            isEnteredNumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func calculationPunched(sender: AnyObject) {
        // operation
        isEnteredNumber = false


firstNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?
```

// There is an error code for this line above that reads "cannot assign a value of type string to value of type double"...?

```
 operation = sender.currentTitle!!
    }

    @IBAction func equalsPunched(sender: AnyObject) {
        // equals
        isEnteredNumber = false
        var result = 0.0


secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?
```

// Error code for line above that reads "? must be followed by call, member lookup or subcrpit"...?

```
        if operation == "+" {
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber
        } else if operation == "-" {
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber
        } else if operation == "x" {
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber
        } else if operation == "/" {
            result = firstNumber / secondNumber
        } /*else if operation == "^" {
            result = pow(firstNumber, secondNumber)
        }*/
        calculatorDisplay.text = "\(result)"
    }

    @IBAction func changeSignPunched(sender: AnyObject) {
        isEnteredNumber = false


firstNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?
```

// There is an Error code for the line above that reads "? must be followed by call, member lookup or subscrpit"...?

```
result = firstNumber * (-1)
        calculatorDisplay.text = "\(result)"
    }

    @IBAction func clearPunched(sender: AnyObject) {
        firstNumber = 0
        secondNumber = 0
        isEnteredNumber = false
        result = 0
        calculatorDisplay.text = "\(result)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to assing string to Double, instead convert string to double using  firstNumber = Float(calculatorDisplay.text?)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a String value to a variable you've already declared to be a Double. Try something like this for the lines that are giving you errors:

```
let firstNumberString = calculatorDisplay.text ?? ""
firstNumber = Double(firstNumberString) ?? 0.0
```

The `??` above is called the *nil coalescing operator*. It will unwrap an optional on the left side or return a default value on the right.